# Private key for RSA decryption C++

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa, private-key

I've tried to write a function to find the private key for RSA using the Extended Euclidean algorithm, I can't find the error but I really don't want to start again from scratch! For certain values it is correct but for others it isn't and I can't work out why, I really appreciate the help and I'm sorry if this question is too vague (I know that tends to annoy people on here). Can anyone find the error? Thank you very much in advance:

```
unsigned long long int  modinv(unsigned long long int  u, unsigned long long int  v)
{
    unsigned long long int  inv, u1, u3, v1, v3, t1, t3, q;
    unsigned long long int  iter;

    u1 = 1;
    u3 = u;
    v1 = 0;
    v3 = v;

    iter = 1;

    while (v3 != 0)
    {

        q = u3 / v3;
        t3 = u3 % v3;
        t1 = u1 + q * v1;

        u1 = v1; v1 = t1; u3 = v3; v3 = t3;
        iter = -iter;
    }

    if (u3 != 1)
        return 0;
    if (iter < 0)
        inv = v - u1;
    else
        inv = u1;
    return inv;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use unsigned values here because it invalidates the algorithm. So instead of `unsigned long long int` you could use `long long int`. Also note that `iter = -iter` will not work as you intended when using unsigned values because it will underflow. Let's say you have `iter = 1` then `-iter` won't be `-1` but instead `18446744073709551615` (=2^64 - 1). The check for `iter < 0` will always be false, too.

For any real life applications you will need much larger numbers than you can fit into 64-bit types. There are many ways of doing this but [GMP](https://gmplib.org) (GNU Multiple Precision lib) has `mpz_powm(r, base, exp, mod)` that you can use in the decryption phase. More info [here](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html#Integer-Exponentiation).

So basically if you had your cipher text `c` and your private key defined as `n` (=p*q) and `d` then you could decrypt `c` into plaintext `m` like this:

```
#include <gmp.h> // requires GMP lib to be installed.
void rsaDecrypt(const mpz_t c, const mpz_t n, const mpz_t d, mpz_t m) {
  mpz_init(m);
  mpz_powm(m, c, d, n); // m = c^d (mod n)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm guessing that the cipher text input `c` is numerical?

Comment: Oh you need GMP installed before you can use this. I was just giving you some ideas. But first try using `long long int` as data type so that it is not unsigned. Then try with your test data again.

Comment: Yeah, that works, fantastic thank you! I'm going to do it myself rather than use `GMP` I think (or try at least).

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for the points. It's a very good thing to implement things yourself to learn.